# jQuery validation plugin odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin for a simple form (name, email, and phone number). Everything is working well except for the phone, which keeps a class of error despite my typing a correct phone number...

Here are the relevant pieces of code :
Form :

```
        <form action="" method="post">
            <h2>Devis gratuit</h2>
            <ul id="errorHolder"></ul>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nom"/>
            </div>
            <div class="field phone-field">
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Téléphone"/>
            </div>
            <div class="field email-field">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            </div>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="optin"/> Recevez des offres promotionnelles</label>
            <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </form>
```

And the set of rules :

```
    rules: { 
    name: "required",
    phone: { 
        required: true, 
        minlength: 8,
            maxLength: 10,
            digits: true
    }, 
    email: { 
        required: true, 
        email: true
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you inputting the phone number? Are you putting it with dashes? +s?

Comment: Nope, it's a French phone number, no dashes, like so : 0101010101

Comment: maxLength may be wrong, try maxlength instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code, it should be:

```
rules: { 
name: "required",
phone: { 
    required: true, 
    minlength: 8,
    maxlength: 10, //not maxLength
    digits: true
}, 
email: { 
    required: true, 
    email: true
}
```

look at the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/maxlength)